# Validation of 2 form fields in a view from one model

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, logic

i don't get it. How can i validate separately 2 form fields in a view. Today i learned, that the validation in model always validates all objects in a model, instead of the object that is given through the param. Now i try to figure out, how to validate only the object that is given trough the formfield.

html

```
    %td
      = form_for opportunity, remote: true do |f|
        = f.text_field :boni_score, placeholder: '0.0 - 6.0'
        = f.submit "Bonität hinzufügen", class: "block btn btn-sm btn-primary marginTop"
    %td
      = form_for opportunity, remote: true do |f|
        = f.text_field :schufa_score, placeholder: '0-9999'
        = f.text_field :schufa_range, placeholder: 'A-P oder Unbekannt', class: 'marginTop'
        = f.submit "Speichern", class: "block marginTop btn btn-sm btn-info"
```

validation

```
    SCHUFA_RANGE =* ('A'..'P')
    SCHUFA_RANGE << 'Unbekannt'

    validates :schufa_range, inclusion: SCHUFA_RANGE, on: :update, if: :boni_score_blank?
    validates :schufa_score, numericality: { only_integer: true }, length: { maximum: 9999, minimum: 0 }, on: :update, if: :boni_score_blank?
    validates :boni_score, numericality: { only_integer: false }, length: { maximum: 6, minimum: 0 }, if: :schufa_blank?

    def boni_score_blank?
      boni_score.blank?
    end

    def schufa_blank?
      schufa_range.blank? || schufa_score.blank?
    end
```

when i press the submit button for the one, then the hole think validates. in fact, i don't get the logic for this. Is it possible to validate each object that is currently in the param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, i have a solution

```
validates :schufa_range, inclusion: SCHUFA_RANGE, on: :update, if: proc { |opportunity| opportunity.schufa_range_changed? }
validates :schufa_score, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 9999 }, on: :update, if: proc { |opportunity| opportunity.schufa_score_changed? }
validates :boni_score, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 6 }, on: :update, if: proc { |opportunity| opportunity.boni_score_changed? }
```

The validation happens now when the model.objects changed.